# Use index value in row section UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, rows

I have two entity classes:

Module.h

```
@interface Module : NSObject {

    NSString *moduleCode4;
    NSString *moduleTitle4;
    NSString *credits4;
    NSString *semester4;
    NSMutableArray *assessmentDetails4;
}
```

AssessmentDetail.h

```
@interface AssessmentDetail : NSObject {

    NSString *assessmentName4;
    NSString *assessmentType4;
    NSString *assessmentWeighting4;
    NSString *assessmentDueDate4;
}
```

I have populated the classes within an NSMutableArray.

In my Table View I have:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    GradeToolAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    return [appDelegate.modules4 count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
    GradeToolAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    Module *aModule = [appDelegate.modules4 objectAtIndex:section];

    return [aModule moduleCode4];

}
```

My problem is that I need the index row path from the module index of the section.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    GradeToolAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //Module *aModule = [appDelegate.modules4];
    AssessmentDetail *anAssess = [module.assessmentDetails4 objectAtIndex:section];
    return [anAssess count];
}
```

I can't understand how to get the number of assessments from the section, can anyone help me out here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already had most of it in tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   GradeToolAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   Module *aModule = [appDelegate.modules4 objectAtIndex:section];
   return [aModule.assessmentDetails4 count];
}
```